# Book where the main character's consciousness is transferred to an artificial body

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

I'm doing a school project which requires me to cite the science-fiction books I've read. I am almost done; I just need the last book, but I can't find the title.

I recall it taking place in a future dystopia where robots/AIs sort of cohabitate; technology here has advanced so far as to become a part of people. Students just look at screens all day, and it is no exaggeration for how they learn. In addition, the main character wakes up with little to no memories about himself, but (*spoilers*) soon discovers he is not all human. He previously had a life and was part of a mind/consciousness-transferring experiment. The man who wants to eventually take over his body is someone who paid for the controversial experiment to be conducted, but these guys help the protagonist to escape to a "natural/no tech" part of country.

Comment: Anyone of my teachers that handed this kind of assignment out would spend an entire school year reading it

Comment: When would this have been published?